# Manipulating array of objects using reduce, correct types are missing

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, reduce

Manipulating array of objects using reduce, correct types are missing

I'm getting array from API response what I need to manipulate before I can use it in my node app.

Here is what I have already done in my app:

```
const array = [
  {
    users: {
      'bc1bff64-ecde-4500-b16d-c1d3a37f2558': {
        points: 368,
        user_id: 'bc1bff64-ecde-4500-b16d-c1d3a37f2558',
        period: 6,
        city: 'london'
      },
      '5124be0c-3faf-444d-9e83-b570ca42c772': {
        points: 358,
        user_id: '5124be0c-3faf-444d-9e83-b570ca42c772',
        period: 6,
        city: 'london'
      }
    }
  },
  {
    users: {
      'bc1bff64-ecde-4500-b16d-c1d3a37f2558': {
        points: 368,
        user_id: 'bc1bff64-ecde-4500-b16d-c1d3a37f2558',
        period: 6,
        city: 'paris'
      },
      '5124be0c-3faf-444d-9e83-b570ca42c772': {
        points: 358,
        user_id: '5124be0c-3faf-444d-9e83-b570ca42c772',
        period: 6,
        city: 'paris'
      }
    }
  },
  {
    users: {
      'bc1bff64-ecde-4500-b16d-c1d3a37f2558': {
        points: 0,
        user_id: 'bc1bff64-ecde-4500-b16d-c1d3a37f2558',
        period: 5,
        city: 'london'
      },
      '5124be0c-3faf-444d-9e83-b570ca42c772': {
        points: 0,
        user_id: '5124be0c-3faf-444d-9e83-b570ca42c772',
        period: 5,
        city: 'london'
      }
    }
  },
  {
    users: {
      'bc1bff64-ecde-4500-b16d-c1d3a37f2558': {
        points: 0,
        user_id: 'bc1bff64-ecde-4500-b16d-c1d3a37f2558',
        period: 5,
        city: 'paris'
      },
      '5124be0c-3faf-444d-9e83-b570ca42c772': {
        points: 0,
        user_id: '5124be0c-3faf-444d-9e83-b570ca42c772',
        period: 5,
        city: 'paris'
      }
    }
  }
];

const getPeriodName = (period: number) =>
  ({ 5: 'PERIOD_5_NAME', 6: 'PERIOD_6_NAME' }[period]);
const getCityName = (city: string) =>
  ({ 'london': 'London', 'paris': 'Paris' }[city]);
const getPointsGain = (points: number) => points + 'blabla';

const reduced = array.reduce((acc, { users }) => {
  Object.entries(users)
    .map(([id, { ...all }]) => {
      acc[id] = acc[id] || {
        id, periods: {}
      };
      acc[id].periods[all.period] = acc[id].periods[all.period] || {
        name: getPeriodName(all.period),
        cities: {}
      };
      acc[id].periods[all.period].cities[all.city] = {
        name: getCityName(all.city),
        points: all.points,
        pointsGain: getPointsGain(all.points)
      };
    });
  return acc;
}, {});
const result = Object.values(reduced);
console.log('result', result);
```

Problem is `reduced` is type `{}` empty object instead of proper full type

[image]

example of a "proper" type

[image]

I want to get this array in an end with correct types:

```json
[
  {
    "id": "bc1bff64-ecde-4500-b16d-c1d3a37f2558",
    "periods": {
      "5": {
        "name": "PERIOD_5_NAME",
        "cities": {
          "london": {
            "name": "London",
            "points": 0,
            "pointsGain": "0blabla"
          },
          "paris": {
            "name": "Paris",
            "points": 0,
            "pointsGain": "0blabla"
          }
        }
      },
      "6": {
        "name": "PERIOD_6_NAME",
        "cities": {
          "london": {
            "name": "London",
            "points": 368,
            "pointsGain": "368blabla"
          },
          "paris": {
            "name": "Paris",
            "points": 368,
            "pointsGain": "368blabla"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "5124be0c-3faf-444d-9e83-b570ca42c772",
    "periods": {
      "5": {
        "name": "PERIOD_5_NAME",
        "cities": {
          "london": {
            "name": "London",
            "points": 0,
            "pointsGain": "0blabla"
          },
          "paris": {
            "name": "Paris",
            "points": 0,
            "pointsGain": "0blabla"
          }
        }
      },
      "6": {
        "name": "PERIOD_6_NAME",
        "cities": {
          "london": {
            "name": "London",
            "points": 358,
            "pointsGain": "358blabla"
          },
          "paris": {
            "name": "Paris",
            "points": 358,
            "pointsGain": "358blabla"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

When consolidating into a single object with `reduce`, even in plain JavaScript, code can be somewhat verbose. It's arguably [not semantically appropriate either](https://dev.to/jasterix/is-reduce-bad-2hhd). With TypeScript, it's even worse, because you have to type the accumulator that gets passed around each iteration.

Consider creating the object *outside*, and listing its types, then iterating over the array with `for..of`. The following compiles with no TS errors:

```
type Periods = {
  [period: number]: {
    name: string;
    cities: {
      [city: string]: {
        name: string;
        points: number;
        pointsGain: string;
      }
    }
  }
};
const acc: {
  [id: string]: { id: string, periods: Periods }
} = {};
for (const { users } of array) {
  Object.entries(users)
    .forEach(([id, { ...all }]) => {
      acc[id] = acc[id] || {
        id, periods: {}
      };
      acc[id].periods[all.period] = acc[id].periods[all.period] || {
        name: getPeriodName(all.period),
        cities: {}
      };
      acc[id].periods[all.period].cities[all.city] = {
        name: getCityName(all.city),
        points: all.points,
        pointsGain: getPointsGain(all.points)
      };
    });
}
const result = Object.values(acc);
```

Note that since you're performing *side effects* after the `Object.entries`, you should use `forEach`, not `.map`. (Only use `.map` when you need to create a *new array* by transforming all elements of an initial array)

Comment: I thought about writing interface, but problem is when I use real data there more than just a single `points` key, so If I need to update something I have to manually change interface or type which not ideal. Is there a way to use automatically generated type?

Comment: I'm using a `type`, not an interface. No, when you need to re-organize data in TypeScript, there's usually no other option other than to exhaustively specify the type of the new data structure.

Comment: Why? If you for example do this http://www.hastebin.net/zurofacuxy.js which is re-organizing data too, why would you assign `number[]` to `array2` if it's already there.

Comment: For *very trivial* manipulations like that, yes, TypeScript can infer it automatically - but for nearly anything more complicated, such inference isn't possible automatically if it's not a single transformation using a built-in JavaScript function, nor if the process that gets carried out is non-functional (TS works best with a functional paradigm, but lots of code makes the most sense using a non-functional paradigm)

Comment: I suppose one way you could get *partway* there would be to run the JavaScript code that applies the transformation, then copy the resulting object into a TypeScript IDE, then copy the IDE's auto-detected type for that code. But objects with dynamic property names will have to be fixed manually (like the `id`s here).